# How does kube-proxy configure services of type nodePort?

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy

When creating a kubernetes service of type [nodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), kube-proxy configures each worker node to listen on a particular port.

How does kube-proxy (in the iptables proxy mode) actually configure this? Is it just done using iptables which opens a port? (not sure if that is even possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kube Proxy uses IPTable and netfilter rules for forwarding traffic from nodeports to pods. Mark Betz's article series on K8's networking is a good read. 
 https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-services-f0cb48e4cc82